# How to store each answer in the answers table? (how to properly store in the array)

Tags: php, arrays

If the user selects quantity “1” for registration type general and “1” for registration type plus and click “Next” and goes to the registration form.

In the form, the user needs to introduce the name and surname for each participant. Then, the registration type general has 3 custom questions associated with it, so for the registration type general the user also need to answer to that 3 custom questions. The questions and the answers answered by the user in the registration form were:

```
Question                                  Answer
input text custom question                text answer
long text custom question:                long answer
checkbox custom question:                 check1
```

With the registration form as it is, and with the answers above, the participant array in the `$request` shows like below. The name, surname, regtypes is stored properly but the answers are not be stored properly in the array:

```
 "participant" => array:2 [▼
        1 => array:15 [▼
          "name" => "John"
          "surname" => "W"
          0 => array:1 [▼
            "answer" => "text answer"
          ]
          1 => array:1 [▼
            "question_id" => "1"
          ]
          2 => array:1 [▼
            "answer" => "long answer"
          ]
          3 => array:1 [▼
            "question_id" => "2"
          ]
          4 => array:1 [▼
            "answer" => "check1"
          ]
          5 => array:1 [▼
            "question_id" => "3"
          ]
          "regtypes" => "1"
        ]
        2 => array:3 [▼
          "name" => "Jake"
          "surname" => "K"
          "regtypes" => "4"
        ]
    ]
```

With the data stored like that using this foreach to insert the participants and the answers in the database shows "Undefined index: answer" in `$participant['answer']`:

```
foreach ($participants_list as $participant) {

    $name = $participant['name'];
    $surname = $participant['surname'];

    $participant_result = Participant::create([
         'name' => $name,
         'surname' => $surname,
         'registration_type_id' => $participant['regtypes']
    ]);

    Answer::create([
        'participant_id' => $participant_result->id,
        'answer' => $participant['answer'],
        'question_id' => $participant['question_id']
    ]);
}
```

Do you know what can be the issue? Maybe is because how the answers and question_id are stored in the array but Im not understanding how to correct that properly.

Registration Form:

```
<form method="post" action="https://proj.test/conf/1/conf-test/registration/store">
  <h6>Participant - 1 - general</h6>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="namegeneral_1">Name</label>
    <input type="text" required id="namegeneral_1" name="participant[1][name]" class="form-control" value="">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="surnamegeneral_1">Surname</label>
    <input type="text" required id="surnamegeneral_1" class="form-control" name="participant[1][surname]" value="">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">input text custom question</label>
    <input type='text' name='participant[1][][answer]' class='form-control' required>
    <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden"  value="1" name="participant[1][][question_id]"/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">long text custom question</label>
    <textarea name='participant[1][][answer]' class='form-control' rows='3' required></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="participant[1][][question_id]"/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">checkbox custom question</label>
    <div class='checkbox-group required'> 
      <div class='form-check'>
        <input type='checkbox' name='participant[1][][answer]' value='select1' class='form-check-input' >
        <label class='form-check-label' for='exampleCheck1'>check1</label>
      </div> 
      <div class='form-check'>
        <input type='checkbox' name='participant[1][][answer]' value='select2' class='form-check-input' >
        <label class='form-check-label' for='exampleCheck1'>check2</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" value="3" name="participant[1][][question_id]"/>
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="participant[1][regtypes]" value="1"/>

  <h6>Participant - 2 - plus</h6>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nameplus_2">Name</label>
    <input type="text" required id="nameplus_2" name="participant[2][name]" class="form-control" value="">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
    <label for="surnameplus_2">Surname</label>
    <input type="text" required id="surnameplus_2" class="form-control" name="participant[2][surname]" value="">
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="participant[2][regtypes]" value="4"/>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, you do this:

```
foreach ($participants_list as $participant) {
```

So `$participant` is:

```
1 => array:15 [▼
          "name" => "John"
          "surname" => "W"
```

However `answer` key is in a sub array of the above, so from the above array it's the next level:

```
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "answer" => "text answer"
```

So `answer` key is not in `$participant` loop value array as per your array, in full:

```
 "participant" => array:2 [▼
        1 => array:15 [▼
          "name" => "John"
          "surname" => "W"
          0 => array:1 [▼
            "answer" => "text answer"
```

`answer` would be in `$participant[0]['answer']`

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how to properly solve that issue? Its necessary to change the participant array structure changing the name attribute of the inputs? Or change in the foreach?

Comment: Changing the foreach to         "foreach ($participants_list as $k => $participant) {" and using $participant[$k]['answer'] it shows the same undefined issue.

Comment: Maybe the array structure needs to be change, because, $participant[0]['answer'] shows "text answer",  $participant[1]['answer'] shows "undefined index_answer",  $participant[2]['answer'] shows "long answer",  $participant[3]['answer'] shows "undefined index answer".

Comment: The problem with the array is you have multiple sub arrays with the key `question_id` and `answer` and the key is just numerical (0, 1, 2, etc) so impossible to identify which "answer" or "question_id" you need. So yes you need to rethink the structure of your array.

Comment: I can't figure out what you are trying to do exactly from that array, but I'll take a guess that you probably want to collate a user with a number of questions, which would probably mean having the user_id as the main key, then a sub array with their details, name etc, then another sub array with the key as "questions" and multiple sub arrays with the keys being the question id and in there the question and answer. If that makes sense. Hard to figure out and explain in a comment

Comment: I want for each participant being registered collect the name and surname inserted in the name and surname fields. And then if a registration type has custom questions associated is necessary to collect that answers that are relative to a specific participant.

Comment: For example the index 1 of the participant array, as it is in the question, it means that for the participant 1 the user that was doing the registration introduced in the form field name, "John", for surname field introduced "w",  the "regtypes" is the id of the registration type "general", that is the registration type where that participant is being registered. And then "text answer", "long answer" and "check1" were the responses of the user to the 3 custom questions that appear on the form for the participant being registered in the registration type "general".

Comment: So, each index of the participant array is to collect the data for that specific participant, in the question are 2 participants because the user selected quantity 1 for the regitration type "general" and 1 for the registration type "plus".

Comment: In your form, instead of `name="participant[1][][question_id]` add the name of the question as a unique identifier. Unless you ask the same question more than once, then there should be unique text, such as `name="participant[][surname]` and `name="participant[][shoe_size]`

Comment: Thanks, but the same question can be asked multiple times, for example if the user select two registration types that have the same question, or even if the user select the same registration type twice and that registration type have a custom question associated, the custom question will appear for both participants thar are being registered.

Comment: Well you need to introduce a unique naming convention to your form array - whatever works for your needs. E.g. if there is a "registration type" then that could be the unique value somewhere in the array, `name="participant[][<?=$unique_question_id;?>]` etc